# SFTP to transfer file

Tags: windows, sftp, transfer

I have created a bat file to transfer files from a pc to server
Everything works fine when a enter command manually but I doo not know how to convert in a script as it will stop after enter password request

```
cd c:\users\user\documents\transfer

sftp user@10.24.200.38

put *.txt
```

The problem is that when the system requests a password, I enter the password but it will stop and I will need to write down the rest of the script

Is there any way to make the script to continue after entering the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is not the problem; the problem is that **scripts do not imitate keyboard input.** They run commands in series, and as far as the script is concerned, the `sftp` command is *still running* – it's showing its own input prompt, but the script cannot do anything with that. Only when 'sftp' exits, the `put` command will be executed within the main Cmd.exe interpreter, not within sftp.

- Use the `sftp -b` option to pass a separate script to the 'sftp' program.

  ```
  cd/d c:\users\user\documents\transfer
  sftp -b c:\whatever\putall.txt user@10.24.200.38
  ```
- Use the `scp` command. (In latest OpenSSH versions it is even SFTP-based.)

  ```
  cd/d c:\users\user\documents\transfer
  scp *.txt user@10.24.200.38:
  ```
- Pipe the commands as explicit input to `sftp` (I am not sure whether this works on Windows).

  ```
  cd/d c:\users\user\documents\transfer
  echo put *.txt | sftp user@10.24.200.38
  ```